# I/O Lockup after RAID5 Volume finishes synchronising

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, raid5

I have a Windows Server 2012 R2 box with a software RAID5 volume (4x 4TB) but for the past few weeks I've been having relability problems with the server where all I/O locks up and I'm forced to reset the box to recover it.

I believe that the problem has to do when the volume finishes syncrhonysing. I've noticed that the server runs just fine while the operation is in progress, but when it finishes the problem occurs (or at least right around when it finishes).

Looking in event viewer I see two events of note:

October 11th:

```
A corruption was discovered in the file system structure on volume E:.
The exact nature of the corruption is unknown. The file system structures need to be scanned online.
```

October 26th *(when the system became unresponsive)*:

```
An I/O operation initiated by the Registry failed unrecoverably.The Registry could not flush hive (file): '\SystemRoot\System32\Config\SAM'.
```

The above event is seen with different hives, as well.

Searching for the registry error event online mentioned problems with the pagefile, for trobleshooting I doubled the size of it, but this did not resolve the problem.

Checkdisk on the volume comes back clean:

```
The type of the file system is NTFS.
Volume label is Data.

WARNING!  F parameter not specified.
Running CHKDSK in read-only mode.

Stage 1: Examining basic file system structure ...


  430848 file records processed.

File verification completed.


  631 large file records processed.


  0 bad file records processed.

Stage 2: Examining file name linkage ...


  450158 index entries processed.

Index verification completed.


  0 unindexed files scanned.


  0 unindexed files recovered.

Stage 3: Examining security descriptors ...
Security descriptor verification completed.


  9656 data files processed.
CHKDSK is verifying Usn Journal...


  363756312 USN bytes processed.

Usn Journal verification completed.

Windows has scanned the file system and found no problems.
No further action is required.

  11445953 MB total disk space.
1545917792 KB in 278938 files.
    101448 KB in 9657 indexes.
         0 KB in bad sectors.
   1031087 KB in use by the system.
     65536 KB occupied by the log file.
   9935162 MB available on disk.

      8192 bytes in each allocation unit.
1465082111 total allocation units on disk.
1271700821 allocation units available on disk.
```

Comment: Do any of the disks report errors?  `Get-Disk | Get-StorageReliabilityCounter`

Comment: @JohnMahowald yes, it reports 3 read errors and 3 corrected errors.